# Conditional Probability given P(B|A)

Tags: probability

Given, P(A) = 0.7, P(B) = 0.5 and P(B|A) = 0.6, Find P(A U B).

My solution: Find P(A and B)[x/0.7=0.6],which is = 0.42  and then apply P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B) which gets you P(A U B) = 0.78.

This gets you the correct answer but I am not sure if this is the method I should follow, I'd like to understand how to deal with such questions appropriately.

Comment: Yes what you have done is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your work is correct. $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\cup B) ~&=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)&&\small\textrm{Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion}\\&=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B\mid A)&&\small\textrm{Definition of conditional probability}\\&= 0.7+0.5-0.7\cdot0.6&&\small\textrm{Substitution of known values}\\&=0.78&&\small\textrm{Calculation}\end{align}$$