Conditional Probability for A and B
My answer is graded as incorrect however I do not see any other way to do this. What am I missing?
Given P(A)=0.7, P(B)=0.5, P(B|A)=0.6 Find P(A union B)
P(A union B) =P(A)+P(B)- P(A intersection B)
P(A intersection B)= P(A) * P(B)=0.35
P(A union B)=0.7 + 0.5-.35=0.85
Edit: apparently A intersection B is ()(∣) not P(A)*P(B) which is what I. have in my notes. That was my error.

You were not told that $A,B$ are independent (indeed, the data shows that they are not).

Might be worth noting:  the given data is not possible.  With $P(A)=.7$ and $P(B)=.5$, $P(A\cap B)≥.2$ but  $P(B,|,A)=.06=\frac {P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$ implies that $P(A\cap B)=.042$   Perhaps you meant $P(B,|,A)=.6$?

sorry yes P(B|A)=.6 not .06

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202615/conditional-probability-given-pba?rq=1

As pointed out by lulu, $A$ and $B$ are not assumed to be independent hence we cannot make a reasoning rest on the fact that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.
In order to compute $P(A\cap B)$, we can use conditional probabilities:
$$
P(A\cap B)=P(B\cap A)=P(B\mid A)P(A)=0.6*0.7=0.42.
$$

the answer is 0.78 and I'm not quite sure why, but this answer was accepted and was also given in a thread I have linked above. apparently A intersection B is ()(∣) not P(A)*P(B) which is what I. have in my notes. That was my error, but not sure why exactly. Is P(A) intersection P(B) not always P(A)*P(B) when the probability is conditional?

@apunc1 $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  So, it isn't that "P(A) intersection P(B) not always P(A)P(B) when the probability is conditional?"  it is that "P(A) intersection P(B) is always not P(A)P(B) when the probability is conditional?"

As to "the answer is 0.78"... that is because Davide's answer here stopped after the step of finding $\Pr(A\cap B)$ and to complete the problem would have you use inclusion-exclusion to find $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)=0.7+0.5-0.42=0.78$, something you demonstrated in your attempt that you already knew how to do and so didn't need repeating here.

@JMoravitz thank you! I was using notes from a lesson prior before we got to conditional probability and didn't realize the rules change.
